# Creating a Zoom Effect on an image on hover using CSS?

Tags: html, class, css

I'm currently trying to create a zoom effect on hover over one of my four images. The problem is most examples usually use tables or mask divs to apply some sort of effect.

Here's one example that implements what I would like [this](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/PhotoWall/fade.html).

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/) is my code so far.

#### HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<img class ="blog" src="http://s18.postimg.org/il7hbk7i1/image.png" alt="">
<img class ="music" src="http://s18.postimg.org/4st2fxgqh/image.png" alt="">
<img class ="projects" src="http://s18.postimg.org/sxtrxn115/image.png" alt="">
<img class ="bio" src="http://s18.postimg.org/5xn4lb37d/image.png" alt="">
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#menu {
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#menu img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 375px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blog {
    height: 375px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.blog:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    height:475px;
    width: 350px;
}

.music {
    height: 375px;
}

.projects {
    height: 375px;
}

.bio {
    height: 375px;
}
```

Answer (score 168):

What about using `CSS3 transform` property and use `scale` which ill give a zoom like effect, this can be done like so,

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image">
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="Some awesome text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

Here's a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/1206/). I removed some of the element to make it simpler, you can always add overflow hidden to the `.image` to hide the overflow of the scaled image.

`zoom` property only works in IE

Comment: And winning the "deep life lessons from code" award, your CSS is chanting "All is ease, all is ease."

Comment: How would you prevent pixelation?

Comment: @Waltari your image size should be 25% (the amount we are zooming in) larger than the content area, so if the thumbnail is 320x240 and we are zooming in by 25% the image should be 400x300.

Answer (score 25):

Here you go.

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/4/

### HTML

```html
<div id="menu">

    <div class="fader">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Yay!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732643/jquery-masonry-and-css3/">
            <img class ="blog" src="http://s18.postimg.org/il7hbk7i1/image.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="fader">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Yay!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732643/jquery-masonry-and-css3/">
            <img class ="blog" src="http://s18.postimg.org/4st2fxgqh/image.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="fader">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Yay!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732643/jquery-masonry-and-css3/">
            <img class ="projects" src="http://s18.postimg.org/sxtrxn115/image.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="fader">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Yay!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732643/jquery-masonry-and-css3/">
            <img class ="blog" src="http://s18.postimg.org/5xn4lb37d/image.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#menu {
    text-align: center; }


.fader {
    /* Giving equal sizes to each element */
    width:    250px;
    height:   375px;

    /* Positioning elements in lines */
    display:  inline-block;

    /* This is necessary for position:absolute to work as desired */
    position: relative;

    /* Preventing zoomed images to grow outside their elements */
    overflow: hidden; }


    .fader img {
        /* Stretching the images to fill whole elements */
        width:       100%;
        height:      100%;

        /* Preventing blank space below the image */
        line-height: 0;

        /* A one-second transition was to disturbing for me */
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -moz-transition:    all 0.3s ease;
        -o-transition:      all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-transition:     all 0.3s ease;
        transition:         all 0.3s ease; }

        .fader img:hover {
            /* Making images appear bigger and transparent on mouseover */
            opacity: 0.5;
            width:   120%;
            height:  120%; }

    .fader .text {
        /* Placing text behind images */
        z-index: -10;     

        /* Positioning text top-left conrner in the middle of elements */
        position: absolute;
        top:      50%;
        left:     50%; }

        .fader .text p {
            /* Positioning text contents 50% left and top relative
               to text container's top left corner */
            margin-top:  -50%; 
            margin-left: -50%; }
```

### Suggestion

Instead of `.fader { inline-block; }` consider using some grid system. Based on your technology of preference, you can go [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html), [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/), [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or their alternatives.

Answer (score 20):

```
.aku { 
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}

.aku:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I like using a background image.  I find it easier and more flexible:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/spzm9/)

**CSS:**

```
#menu {
    max-width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.zoomimg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 375px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.zoomimg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: 150% 150%;
}
.blog {
    background-image: url(http://s18.postimg.org/il7hbk7i1/image.png);
}
.music {
    background-image: url(http://s18.postimg.org/4st2fxgqh/image.png);
}
.projects {
    background-image: url(http://s18.postimg.org/sxtrxn115/image.png);
}
.bio {
    background-image: url(http://s18.postimg.org/5xn4lb37d/image.png);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="blog zoomimg"></div>
    <div class="music zoomimg"></div>
    <div class="projects zoomimg"></div>
    <div class="bio zoomimg"></div>
</div>
```

### [DEMO 2 with Overlay](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/spzm9/2/)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a background image for this, you're going to loose all the amazing image related SEO that comes with using a image tag and alt attributes.

Comment: I think this is great, but you do lose all the utility of the img tag.

Comment: If the image is not relevant for SEO, I found this solution cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

Simply:

```
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
```

This will allow the element to assign an animation via css.

```
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

This will make it grow!

Answer (score 7):

```
.item:hover img 
{
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

this way you can zoom any image with simple animation. If you need a complete tutorial here is a official tutorial: http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/image-zoom-in-on-hover-using-css3.php

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION 1:** You can download [zoom-master](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/). 

**SOLUTION 2:**  Go to [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3) .

**SOLUTION 3:**  Your own codes

```css
.hover-zoom {
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
     transition:all 0.3s
 }
.hover-zoom:hover {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     transform: scale(1.5)
 }
```

```html
<img class="hover-zoom"  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewRqh.jpg" 
     width="100px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="item">
  <img src="yamahdi1.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="50" height="58">
  <img src="yamahdi.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="50" height="58">
  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
```

> css:

```
.item img {

  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
-o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 1s ease;
```

just want to make a note on the above transitions only need

```
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
transition: all 1s ease;
```

and -ms- certainly doenst work for IE 9 i dont know where you got that idea from.

Comment: IE10 (the first stable version of IE to support transition) does not require the -ms- prefix, previous unstable builds do and same goes for -moz- and -o-, current versions don't require but previous builds do.

Comment: -ms- is completely not required as it doesn't offer a solution for any of the IE browsers to get the transition to work. You use prefix to get the specific rule to work you don't just throw them in for fun.

Comment: -ms- is a vendor prefix that they dropped on the release of IE 10, meaning previous versions like IE 9 still use the vendor prefix, many people sadly use IE 9 to this day, now when it comes to the `transition` property IE officially brought `transition` in IE 10 so there for it doesn't require it, however if you want to be 100% there are versions of IE 9 that are unstable that use `-ms-transition`.

Comment: That's false transitions do not work in IE9 with the vendor prefix. -ms- is a completely pointless prefix for transitions.

Comment: Unstable versions do. I'm not going to argue with you over 1 line of code and the fact you're saying `-moz-` and `-o-` aren't required shows you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: They aren't LOL the fact you think they do shows what you know. here is also some proof on the matter http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions. only -webkit- prefix is ever needed for transitions you part time DEV's need to start stabilizing your code and learn what is actually required in practice.

Comment: Hit the 'Show all' tab mate and you'll see all the versions `-moz-` and `-o-` are required, cheers!

Comment: Do you see -ms- anywhere also -o- on the opera mobile actually doesn't make transitions work so its pointless and -moz- for the quick successive 2011 releases is pointless because you are literally talking about a tiny handful of user who will 100% be devs & institutions not using the web as a general user but for platform purposes.

But still the main argument remains -ms- is totally useless and not required in the slightest.

there is no need for -moz- or -o-

And there is 100% no need for -ms-

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .img-wrap:hover img {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    .img-wrap img {
        display: block;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://www.sampleimages/images.jpg"/> // Your image
    </div>
```

This code is only for zoom-out effect.Set the div "img-wrap" according to your styles and insert the above style results zoom-out effect.For zoom-in effect you must increase the scale value(eg: for zoom-in,use
  transform: scale(1.3);

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:200,300,400,700&subset=latin-ext');
 body{ font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif; color:white;}
 #lists {
   width: 350px;
   height: 460px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color:#222222;
   padding:0px;
   float:left;
    margin: 10px;
 }
 
 .listimg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 220px;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
  
 }
  #lists .listimg img {
   width: 350px;
   height: 220px;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   transition: all 0.3s;
 }
 #lists:hover{cursor: pointer;}
 #lists:hover > .listimg img {
   -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
   transform: scale(1.3);
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   filter: blur(5px);
 }

#lists h1{margin:20px; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:0px; }
#lists p{margin:20px;}

.listdetail{ text-align:right; font-weight:200; padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:6px;}
```

```html
<div id="lists">
<div class="listimg">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WeEw5I-wk2UO-y0u3Wsv8MxprCJjxTyTzvwdEc9pcdTsZVj_yK5thdtXNDKoZcUOHlegFhx7=w1920-h914-rw">
</div>
<div class="listtext">
<h1>Eyes Lorem Impsum Samet</h1>
<p>Impsum Samet Lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="listdetail">
<p>Click for More Details...</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="lists">
<div class="listimg">
  <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/fqK7aQ7auobK_NyXRYCsL9SOpVj6SoYqVlgbOENw6IqQvEWzym_3988798NlkGDzu0MWnR-7nxIhj7g=w1920-h870-rw">
</div>
<div class="listtext">
<h1>Two Frogs Lorem Impsum Samet</h1>
<p>Impsum Samet Lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="listdetail">
<p>More Details...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.zoom {

  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom img {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.zoom:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Image Zoom On Hover</h1>
<div class="zoom">
  <img src="/image-path-url" alt="">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to remove your answer from low quality post.

Answer (score -3):

Add jQuery JavaScript library together with the jquery.zbox.css and jquery.zbox.js to your webpage.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.zbox.css">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.zbox.min.js"></script>
```

Add a group of thumbnails with links pointing to the full sized images into the webpage.

```
<a class="zb" rel="group" href="1.png" title="Image 1">
  <img src="thumb1.png">
</a>
<a class="zb" rel="group" href="2.png" title="Image 2">
  <img src="thumb2.png">
</a>
<a class="zb" rel="group" href="3.png" title="Image 3">
 <img src="thumb3.png">
</a>
```

Call the function on document ready. That's it.

In the view source do:

```
$(".zb").zbox();
```

Comment: OP asked for a way to do this in CSS. A jQuery answer is not helpful here.