# How to zoom in on K2 item module images

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

This is the website I am working on > http://legendofindia.com/

I have been stuck on the "What's New" of the page because the client wants the images displayed to have a mouse over effect that zooms in the picture.

kicker: when the picture zooms in the container box shouldn't move. and it has to be full css

Been trying a lot of approach editing the css files and been researching also but to no avail. I hope you guys can help me because my deadline is pretty close and this is the last thing I need to finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

may be you can do like this jsfiddle.net/27Syr/5/

taken from [Creating a Zoom Effect on an image on hover using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css)