# move element in DOM but not on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a lightbox style plugin that opens an image in fullscreen and adds text about it next to it. I need a zoom animation, that just zooms the small image up to fill the screen. Since the small image is in a column layout, i need to move it out of the current dom structure. However i am unable to do so while doing the zoom animation.

So my question is:
Is there any way to move an element in the dom, or just change its position to fixed and keep its position on screen? I have jQuery avaliable

Comment: @deadpool Yes, but doing that it will be hard to do the zoom animation.

Comment: What about using a jQuery plugin or similar? there is plenty of stuff like this on the web

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get it done, this plugin could do the job.

[magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)

Otherwise, I'd put the image in a container of the same size so that you can change the image display property without having your layout get screwed up.

You don't need to move the element in your DOM. Just change the css.

Also [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css) could possibly help you.