# How to zoom part of an image in html?

Tags: html, css, image, zooming

I want to zoom part of an image in html.
To show just part of image in html, I have written a code  in first comment.
I want to zoom this shown part.How can I do it.

```
<!DOCTYOE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            position: relative;
        }

        #clip {
            position: absolute;
            clip: rect(0, 120, 80px, 0);
            /* clip: shape(top, right, bottom, left); NB 'rect' is the only available option */
        }

        </div>
    </style>
</head>
<div class="container"> <img src="images10.png" /> </div>
<div class="container"> <img id="clip" src="images10.png" /> </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is long discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code which will zoom specified part :

```
#clip { zoom: 150%; }
```

FYI : [More info here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/)