# Margin of -15px on hover to make div bigger pushes bootstrap columns below lower

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's mostly in the title. I am displaying products in divs on my website. On hover, I make them increase in size by applying a margin of -15px to give them a nice hover effect. When I hover over any of them, it is fine except for the right-most ones, as it pushes the products below it away into the Bootstrap row below. Here are images:

Good (hover over a middle one):

[image]

Bad (hover over the right-most one):

[image]

Here is the code:

Search results page:

```
    <div id="search-results">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'product-template', foreach: allProducts }"></div>
</div>
```

Product template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="product-template">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-2" style="margin-top:20px; padding: 25px;">
        <div class="product-item">
            <div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'../../the_vegan_repository/product_images/' + product.imagePath + '\')' }"
                 style= "height: 160px; 
                        border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
                        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                        color: white; 
                        background: center no-repeat;
                        background-size:cover;
                        vertical-align:bottom;">
            </div>
            <div style="height: 110px; padding: 10px; background: #fc4747;">
                <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: product.brand" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:5px;"></h6>
                <h6 class="medium-text" data-bind="text: product.name" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: white; margin-bottom:5px;display: inline;"></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

CSS:

```
div.product-item:hover {
  margin: -15px;
}
div.product-item {
  border: 5px solid #fc4747;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

How do I stop the Bootstrap grid system from pushing the bottom row into the row lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on hover, I make them increase in size by applying a margin of -15px

Use `transform: scale(x);` instead of `margin: -15px;` as transforms do not affect the box-model of the element.

[CSS Transforms Module Level 1:](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)

> Note: Transformations do affect the visual layout on the canvas, but have no affect on the CSS layout itself. This also means transforms do not affect results of the Element Interface Extensions getClientRects() and getBoundingClientRect(), which are specified in [CSSOM-VIEW].

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move it up by a certain amount, use `transform: translateY(-15px)` instead of changing the `margin` on the `div.product-item:hover` class. To move it in a context that does not interrupt the rest of the document. Or you can use `transform: scale(1.2)` to make things bigger.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's actually changing the dimentions of the div when you change the margin which in turn affects others. Check out this link . It gives an example on how to give such zoom effect.
[Creating a Zoom Effect on an image on hover using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css)