# Html expand on mouse over

Tags: html, mouseover, expand

I need to make an expand on mouse over element which doesn't move text next to/below/above it out of HTML only.

This is the html that I need to do this

```
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEjI4YVeORS9Xqal2/giphy.gif" alt=""style="width:12px;height:18px;">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post code and effort

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css

Answer (score 0):

Position the surrounding content absolutely and then add a `img:hover` selector to your CSS. [See this fiddle]
(https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/03azgrvq/) for an example using divs instead of images but you'd just need to change the selectors. The code below shows a hover selector but view the Fiddle for the positioning.

```
img:hover {
    // change these to your expand requirements
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: *Note* it must be able to be copied and pasted while still keeping the expanding properties

Answer (score 0):

Add this code, which expands your image height and width on mouse over.

HTML,

```
<div id="img">
<img src="#" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
transition:0.6s ease;
}
img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#img:hover{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```