# Zoom in on specific region of image

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to guide the zoom transition to zoom in on the top of the image or the bottom or any other specific region? I am currently doing this:

```css
.grow { 
     transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
}
.grow:hover { 
     transform: scale(8); 
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="grow"/>
```

How would I expand on that?

Comment: Check this question . This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757036/creating-a-zoom-effect-on-an-image-on-hover-using-css

Answer (score -1):

Ok, to begin with, I have taken the code from this [website](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3).

Fast-forward to the end of the tutorial and you will get the code.

THE CODE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var native_width = 0;
  var native_height = 0;

  $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (!native_width && !native_height) {
      var image_object = new Image();
      image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

      native_width = image_object.width;
      native_height = image_object.height;
    } else {
      var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();
      var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
      var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

      if (mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0) {
        $(".large").fadeIn(100);
      } else {
        $(".large").fadeOut(100);
      }
      if ($(".large").is(":visible")) {
        var rx = Math.round(mx / $(".small").width() * native_width - $(".large").width() / 2) * -1;
        var ry = Math.round(my / $(".small").height() * native_height - $(".large").height() / 2) * -1;
        var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

        var px = mx - $(".large").width() / 2;
        var py = my - $(".large").height() / 2;
        $(".large").css({
          left: px,
          top: py,
          backgroundPosition: bgp
        });
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.magnify {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.large {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg') no-repeat;
  display: none;
}
.small {
  display: block;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.magnify {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.large {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg') no-repeat;
  display: none;
}
.small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="magnify">

  <div class="large"></div>
  <img class="small" src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/iphone.jpg" width="200" />

</div>

<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/prefixfree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This seems like you are zooming in on the center of the image. I believe my code does that too. How would you modify this to zoom in on the top of the image?

Comment: Check my code(well not my code) out. Now you can zoom in on ANY PART OF THE IMAGE.

Comment: You should know how to modify the code to get the desired result.