# CSS on hover size without margin

Tags: html, css, hover, size, margin

currently I am trying to get my navigation bar elements bigger on mouseover. But when I mouseover them the rest of the website is moving a bit down and it looks awful.
Is there a way where I can make the text in the navigation bar bigger without influencing the other elements of the website?

```css
nav {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.nav{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: calibri;
    padding-top: 2px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.nav:hover {
    font-size: 130%;
    opacity: 0.6;    
}

.LLHashtag {
    width: 370px;
    margin: 0 Auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 5px;   
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: 600; 
    color: black;
    border-top: solid black 2px;
    font-family: "helvetica Neue";
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Home</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Über</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Motivation</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Kontakt</a>
    <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Impressum</a>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="LLHashtag">#LifeLetics</h1>
```

Comment: please attach your code?

Comment: You should post your code first

Comment: please attached your code.

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15757620/6649350) I hope it will work for your requirement.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't effect it at all. I added my code so maybe you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can use css transform for the text on your navbar e.g. `transform: scale(1.2)`

```
.element:hover{
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

this will not affect other content on the page
also you will need `display: inline-block;` to apply this rule on header links

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: calibri;
  padding-top: 2px;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.LLHashtag {
  width: 370px;
  margin: 0 Auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  border-top: solid black 2px;
  font-family: "helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Home</a>
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Über</a>
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Motivation</a>
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Kontakt</a>
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.de">Impressum</a>
</nav>
<h1 class="LLHashtag">#LifeLetics</h1>
```

Comment: @Jahrens then you need to provide minimal working example (html+css). easiest way is to use `add snippet` button in the `edit question` form

Comment: Thanks, I've inserted it.

Comment: @Jahrens yw, also you might want to add backface-visibility: hidden; then text transition goes better

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `transform: scale(1.2)`. Do not forget to change `1.2` with your desired scale.